# How to stop user from using the same input?

Tags: python

How can I stop the user from using the same exact name for the team members?

```
for i in range(teamMembers):
    while True:
       try: 
         teamMember = input("Enter the name of team member {} :".format(i+1))


      if not teamMember:
         raise ValueError("Team member can not be blank")

      elif teamMember.isdigit():
         raise ValueError("Team member name can not be a number")

                    else: 
                        break

                except ValueError as e:
                    print (e)
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting, python is layout sensitive. You aren't showing what you are doing with the `teamMember` variable so hard to help on how you can test that the name doesn't already exist.

Comment: Keep a list of previous members?

Answer (score 1):

```
members = []
for i in range(teamMembers):
    teamMember = input("Enter the name of team member {} :".format(i+1))
    if not teamMember:
        raise ValueError("Team member can not be blank")
    if teamMember in members:
        raise ValueError("This name already exist")
    members.append(teamMember)
```

I think this is what you want - if nothing will fail in `try` block but you still want to `raise` exception, you can just `raise` directly.